# Nuxt `head` property shows errors when using computed properties

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vetur

I'm using Nuxt.js using `head() { }` to set SEO metadata.

Within this, if I access computed properties, Vetur shows:

```
Property 'domain' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance {...}>'.
```

```js
import Vue from "vue";
export default Vue.extend({
   head(){ 
       const domain = this.domain;
       return {};
   },
   computed: {
       domain() {
           return this.$route.params.domain || '';
       }
   }
});
```

The app renders fine server-side, but not sure why I'm seeing these errors in VSCode.

Comment: Do you use typescript? Otherwise, you could just disable that one.

Comment: @kissu yes, I use typescript. It's just strange that it's showing errors in VSCode, but the SSR works fine.

Comment: I don't see why this is strange. A missing type is not a runtime error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer (https://github.com/nuxt-community/typescript-template/issues/219) that fixes this problem:

add: `import { MetaInfo } from 'vue-meta'` and declare `head(): MetaInfo {...}`

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import { MetaInfo } from 'vue-meta'
export default Vue.extend({
   head(): MetaInfo { 
       const domain = this.domain;
       return {};
   },
   computed: {
       domain() {
           return this.$route.params.domain || '';
       }
   }
});
```